# Octopus Deploy : "Skipping this step as no matching targets were found"

Tags: octopus-deploy

We have several projects in Octopus Deploy Cloud and we have never had issues deploying to the existing targes.

As of today, all deployment steps get skipped with this message in the logs:

> Skipping this step as no matching targets were found

This has affected all projects, all channels and all environments (we have five different environments in five different AWS accounts).

> == Skipped: Step 1: Create or Update IIS Website == 10:40:29
>   Verbose  |     Searched for targets: 10:40:29   Verbose  |     *
>   specifically matching these ids: Machines-534 and Machines-535
>                       |     * that are enabled
>                       |     * with no id exclusions
>                       |     * with no environment exclusions
>                       |     * has a role that overlaps: APII
>                       |     * with no tenant exclusions
>                       |     * has a health status of: Healthy or HasWarnings 10:40:29   Info     |     Skipping this step as no
>   matching targets were found

The above is part of the raw log.

All deployment targets in the given environment and channel are Healthy (green).  Any idea what can be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

You have encountered [this bug](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/6051). This issue can be resolved by upgrading to `2019.10.12` or later.

Comment: You might want to describe a little about the bug.  Stackoverflow likes questions to be answered in line (at least a summary).  If the link to "this bug" went away, that might render this answer less valuable.